# How do I properly transform missing datapoints as 0 in Prometheus?

Tags: time-series, prometheus

We have an alert we want to fire based on the previous `5m` of metrics (say, if it's above 0). However, if the metric is `0` it's not written to prometheus, and as such it's not returned for that time bucket.

The result is that we may have an example data-set of:

```
-60m  |  -57m  |  -21m  |  -9m  |  -3m    <<< Relative Time
   1  ,  0    ,    1    ,  0    ,  1      <<< Data Returned
```

which ultimately results in the alert firing every time the metric is above `0`, not only when it's above `0` for `5m`. I've tried writing our query with `OR on() vector()` appended to the end, but it does funny stuff with the returned dataset:

```
values:Array[12]
 0:Array[1539021420,0.16666666666666666]
 1:Array[1539021480,0]
 2:Array[1539021540,0]
 3:Array[1539021600,0]
 4:Array[1539021660,0]
 5:Array[1539021720,0]
 6:Array[1539021780,0]
 7:Array[1539021840,0]
 8:Array[1539021900,0]
 9:Array[1539021960,0]
 10:Array[1539022020,0]
 11:Array[1539022080,0]
```

For some reason it's putting the "real" data at the front of the array (even though my starting time is well before `1539021420`) and continuing from that timestamp forward.

**What is the proper way to have Prometheus return `0` for data-points which may not exist?**

<sub>To be clear, this isn't an alertmanager question -- I'm using a different tool for alerting on this data.</sub>